# Using toString() in C# get exponential value for big Integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssis

I have script task transformation on my SSIS package.
Basically i write data(sql query) to txt file using scrip task.

this piece of code `sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())` couldn't convert this value `11398069` properly. I think i need to use `bigInt.ToString()` but does it work with any value.
11398069 -- after export txt shows this value as `1.13981e+007` instead of `11398069`
Let me know.

Here is the code below.

```
sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
 For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
  sw.Write("5|")
   For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
    If Not Convert.IsDBNull(dr(i)) Then
     **sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())**
    End If
    If i < iColCount - 1 Then
     sw.Write("|")
    End If
  Next
 sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
 Next
```

Values could be really anything.
For instance(Sample values).
120
120.09290
1.23443
ABC
ZZZZZZZ
11398069 -- after export txt shows this value as 1.13981e+007 instead of 11398069

Let me know how to handle this

Comment: Did you get any error message? If yes could you post that message?

Comment: No error, didn't get the correct values as i mentioned. I see this value/data "1.13981e+007" instead of correct data(11398069).

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server `bigint` type maps to the .NET `System.Int64` or VB `Long` type. This should do it if the table column is really a `bigint`:

```
DirectCast(dr(i), Long).ToString()
```

You also say that the values could be anything. As an example you write "ABC". Is your table column really typed as `bigint` or is it a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` column? In the latter case it could just contain the value formatted as `1.13981e+007`.

Another question is, what is `sw`? Could it be that the `Write` command performs some kind of unwanted formatting?

If `dr(i)` returns a `Double` then it could be formaatted in the exponeial format as well. This would help:

```
DirectCast(dr(i), Double).ToString("0")
```

---

**UPDATE**

You might have to do something like

```
If Not dr.IsDBNull(i) Then
    Dim s As String
    If dr.GetFieldType(i) Is GetType(Double) Then
        s = dr.GetDouble(i).ToString("0")
    Else
        s = dr(i).ToString()
    End If
    sw.Write(s)
End If
```

It really depends on the type of the very column that is wrongly formatted. The fact that the number is formatted with the exponential format is a strong hint that the number's type (SQL type and especially the VB type it is mapped to) is in fact not an integer type (Integer, Long) but some decimal or floating type (Single, Double, Decimal). The very number stored might have no decimal fractions and be integer but this does not make it an integer number **type**.

Set a breakpoint on the `sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())` line and inspect the runtime type returned by `dr(i)`. Or insert the line

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( _
                               String.Format("col({0}) = {1}", i, dr.GetFieldType(i)))
```

And display the Ouput Window (menu *Debug > Windows > Output*).

Comment: 1. SW is Stream Writer Dim sw As New StreamWriter(Path, False).

Comment: 1. SW is Stream Writer Dim sw As New StreamWriter(Path, False).           2. It's not about what's DB column. I run Select SQL query and write data to txt file. I need to add header/trailer/detail records to text so loop thru the data using above code. There will be variety of data coming from different columns. Everything works fine expect for big Int values. I'm not sure how to use directCast in relation to Stream Writer.

Comment: It really depends on the type of the column that gets formatted the wrong way. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user1810575 If none of Olivier's 3 options work, then... is it clear what SQL data type the *query* is giving the column?  If that question is giving trouble... you could temporarily change your query to a `SELECT <columnList> INTO <newTableName>...`, which would save the query results into SQL table `<newTableName>`, and then look at that table to see the SQL data-type of the column-in-question... so at least you know what *SQL* data type is being mapped.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem here is that you are just calling ToString() on the default type returned from the datareader, which is Object. You need to give the compiler more help eg cast to double then use ToString("R") or, use one of the Get methods etc etc